# Redux | Why this store's parameter type changes after second click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to push a new value in the store's state. It works fine the first time I click on the button "Add item", but the second time I got the following error: "`state.basket.push is not a function`". I configure the action to console log the state and got the following results:

**1st** click: {...}{basketItems: Array [ "44" ]}

**2nd** click: Object {basketItems: 0 }

Why the variable type is changing from array to an int?

Here is the code for the rendered component:

```
function Counter({ basketItems,additem }) {

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={additem}>Add item</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  basketItems: state.counterReducer.basketItems,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    additem: ()=>dispatch({type: actionType.ADDITEM, itemName:'Dummy text'  }),

  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Counter);
```

And the reducer looks like this:

```
import {ADDITEM} from "../actions/types";

const initialState = { basket: [], };

export default function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADDITEM:
      console.log(state);
      // let newBasket = state.basket.push('44');
      return { 
        ...state,
        basket: state.basket.push('44')
        };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

I'm copying the state before updating the basket to prevent weird behaviors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two problems here:

- `state.basket.push()` *mutates* the existing `state.basket` array, which is not allowed in Redux
- It also returns the new size of the array, not an actual array

So, you're not doing a correct immutable update, and you're returning a value that is not an array.

A correct immutable update here would look like:

```js
return {
  ...state,
  basket: state.basket.concat("44")
}
```

Having said that, you should really be using [our official Redux Toolkit package](https://redux-toolkit.js.org), which will let you drastically simplify your reducer logic and catch mistakes like this.